# Open data for creating music

Tags: data-request, medical, music

I am looking to create a track based on some medical data, assigning each value to a given scale (say pentatonic scale).

I need to find some medical data that's accessible and preferably in an easy to manipulate format.

Comment: open data formats can be edited/manipulated with numerous technologies, the sky is the limit most of the time. some formats/technologies are more performant/advanced/etc., it truly depends on what the dataset is, as well as what format it is in.

Comment: Right, so where do you recommend me look @albert?

Comment: This is almost too open-ended to answer. If you just want "some medical data," there's plenty of medical data available through the [medical tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical).

Comment: @csk I think the OP needs medical data and music data on the same person, so not that open-ended.

Comment: @AleksanderJess what kind of music do you want to create? If you find a list of songs people listen to and their medical data, is that sufficient, or do you also need the music to be in a format where you can learn and generate music (e.g. generating piano music using MIDI tracks)?

Comment: @PeeyushKushwaha it could be electronic. I want to assign each value to a step of a scale, and therefore create an synth track this way.